# getting the original content, encoding hexes and bitvector

Tags: python-3.x, codec

Let's say I have these methods

```
def convert_to_bv(a):
    if type(a) is str:
        return BitVector.BitVector(textstring=a)
    if type(a) is int:
        return BitVector.BitVector(intVal = a)
def convert_to_hex(b):
    return BitVector.BitVector.get_bitvector_in_hex(b)
```

Now I also am using codecs.encode/decode.

A test case:

```
a = '12324'
print(a)
b = codecs.encode(a, 'hex')
print(b)
c= codecs.decode(b, 'hex')
print(c)


x = BitVector.BitVector(textstring=a)
y = convert_to_bv(a)
print(str(x)==str(y)) #this comes out as true
m = convert_to_hex(x)
n = convert_to_hex(y)
print(m, n)

o = convert_to_bv(codecs.decode(m, 'hex'))
print(str(o), str(y)) #true
```

The problem is, I don't seem to be able to get back to the value of a.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind!

```
o = (codecs.decode(m, 'hex'))
print(str(o), a)
```

This works.